# different classes for listener events

Tags: java, events

I am working on a simple application which uses the actionListener and WindowListener events. The aim is to make the default_close_operation work according the clicked button(s) added to the panel. This can easily be done using inner classes, however I want to use different classes for each listener event. Here's the code:

```
//test.java
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
public class test extends JFrame 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new test();
    }

    private JButton button, exit;
    action a1 = new action();
    close c1 = new close();
    public test()
    {
        this.setSize(200,200);
        this.setTitle("test ");
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        button = new JButton("Button");
        exit = new JButton("Exit");
        exit.addActionListener(c1);
        button.addActionListener(a1);
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(button);
        p1.add(exit);
        this.add(p1);
    }
```

}

//action.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class action extends WindowAdapter implements ActionListener
{
    JButton b1;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        b1 = (JButton)e.getSource();
        if(b1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("button"))
        {
            b1.setText("Clicked");
        }
        else if(b1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

//close.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class close extends WindowAdapter
{
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {
        exit.doClick(); //WRONG as no variable exists with exit name.
    }
}
```

Everything is fine except in close.java class. How do I point the WindowClosing method to action class so that program terminates in a correct fashion?

Comment: What behaviour do you want to achieve? Shall it be required to press the button first, before closing the application window, or do you want to close the window with a button, ...?

Comment: In Java, class names generally begin with a capital letter.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with this code, but your listeners look a bit messed up. Maybe you can help us understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: I apologize for the messiness of this code. I am a newbie, and just want the close button of window to work as if I pressed the "exit" button I added to the frame. This can be done by using inner classes easily. But I want to use a different class for each different event, bypassing the inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend ActionListener just the way you did for Action class and exit the way you handled things in Action.java

```
//from your code
else if(b1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need JFrame to perform operation in your own action listener like this

```
public class MyListener extends WindowAdapter implements ActionListener
{

    JFrame frame ;
    public MyListener(JFrame component) {
        this.frame = component;
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        if(actionCommand.equals("Exit")) {
            //When the last displayable window within the Java virtual 
            // machine (VM) is disposed of, the VM may terminate
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
             // perfrom operation after window closed
        Component component = e.getComponent();
        String name = component.getName();
        System.out.println("Component " + name + " is closing");

    }


    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("window is closed");
    }

}
```

Add listener to the Frame and Button

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");   
    buttonExit = new JButton("Exit");
    listener = new MyListener(this);
    frame.addWindowListener(listener);
    buttonExit.addActionListener(listener);
```